# Should linear solver be converging when Coloring is beign computed

Tags: openmdao

I had to add some circular dependencies to my model and thus adding NonlinearBlockGS and LinearBlockGS to the Group with the circular dependency. I get messages like this

> LN: LNBGSSolver 'LN: LNBGS' on system 'XXX' failed to converge in 10
> iterations.

in the phase where it's finding the Coloring of the problem. There is a Dymos trajectory as part of the problem, but the circular dependency is not in the Trajectory group, it's upstream. It however converges very easily when actually solving the problem. The number of FWD solves is the same as it was before-- everything seem to work fine. Should I be worried about anything?

Comment: just to be sure, your talking about total derivative coloring right?

Comment: yes, that's right. I use the declare_coloring() on the entire problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way our total derivative coloring works is that we replace partial derivatives with random numbers and then solve the linear system. So the linear solver should be converging. Now, whether or not it should converge with LNBGS in 10 iterations... probably not.

Its hard to speak diffinitively when putting random numbers into a matrix to invert it... but generally speaking it should remain invertible (though we can't promise). That does not mean that it will remain easily invertible. How close does the linear residual get during the coloring? it is decreasing, but slowly. Would more iteration let it get there?

If your problem is working well, I don't think you need to freak out about this. If you would like it to converge better, it won't hurt anything and might give you better coloring. You can increase the iprint of that solver to get more information on the convergence history.

Another option, if your system is small enough, is to try using the DirectSolver instead of LNBGS. For most models with less than 10,000 variables in them a DirectSolver will be overall faster than the LNBGS. There is a nice symetry to using LNBGS with NLGBS ... but while the nonlinear solver tends to be a good choice (i.e. fast and stable) for cyclic dependencies the same can't be said for its linear counter part.

So my go-to combination if NLBGS and DirectSolver. You can't always use the DirectSolver. If you have distributed components in your model, or components that use the matrix-free derivative APIs (`apply_linear`, `compute_jacvec_product`), then LNBGS is a good option. But if everything is explicit components with `compute_partials` or implicit components that provide partials in the `linearize` method then I suggest using the DirectSolver as your first option.

Comment: Thank you Justin, switching to DirectSolver fixed it, and it seems to be faster too

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have discovered a coloring performance issue in OpenMDAO.  When we compute coloring, internally we replace the component partials with random arrays matching the declared sparsity.  Since we're not trying to find an actual solution when we compute coloring, we probably don't need to iterate more than once in any given system.  And we shouldn't be generating convergence warnings when computing the coloring. I don't think you need to be worried in this case.  I'll put a story in our bug tracker to look into this.

Comment: Yes I was thinking it probably wasn't converging because the coloring algorithm is just feed in small random numbers, on a completely different scale of that the actual numbers that it will see during the actual run so it could have a hard time.  I had tested convergence of the NLBGS / LNBGS on the group in a standalone test with the right scale of inputs, which worked, so that's probably it.